# How to display '.cgal' File generated by CGAL:mcfskel

Tags: graphics, cgal

I'm new to CGAL and in the fields of computer graphics. I'm currently interested in doing CGAL:Mean Curvature Skeletonization. I tested the simple example program and it works. As a result, it generated a 'skel.cgal' files, which i think is the points for the generated 1D skeletal.

The problem is i don't know how to display it because normally it will be '.off' file format. I think about converting it to '.off' but don't know where to start. Hope you guys can help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output is a set a polylines. The format is:

`n1 x1 y1 z1 ... xn1 yn1 zn1
...
ni x1 y1 z1 ... xni yni zni`

The first number is the number of points for a polyline, followed by the 3D points.

If you want to have a look at it you can try the CGAL Polyhedron 3D demo.
You can compile it yourself from sources or use the precompiled windows [version](http://www.cgal.org/demo/4.7/polyhedron_3.zip) with its required [dlls](http://www.cgal.org/demo/4.7/CGAL-demoDLLs.zip).

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. Do you have a precompiled for Mac?